# It is possible to run a timer job in Office 365 online?

Tags: office-365

Is it possible to run a timer job every 1 hour for a list in office 365? There should be a bolean column in that list. Once the list item contains the value "true", it should be changed to "false" every 1 hour when the timer runs.

If there is any code using napa in office 365 please share the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any type of feature that requires access to Central Administration (timer jobs, etc.) or equivalent server side changes will not be available to the subscriber of Office 365 as the farm may be shared.  Please take a look at the links below which may further give you an idea to do your requirement.

Service Descriptions for Office 365 for Enterprises:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13602

Developing for SPO with Sandbox Solutions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365trainingcourse_session-2_unit.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335711.aspx

Custom workflows with SharePoint Designer 2010:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/CH010373544.aspx

SharePoint Online for Office 365 Developer Guide:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4387e030-73dc-48e7-ac95-abc043b9335a

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147180.aspx

[Source](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/p/58085/212235.aspx)

Comment: Yes agree, it's not be available for Office 365.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't possible to create a timer job on SharePoint online or anything that uses SSOM (Server-side object model).

But you can create a Windows Azure Timer Job and use CSOM (Client-side object model) as an alternative to a full thrust timer job.

SharePoint Timer Jobs running as Windows Azure Web Jobs: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2014/04/07/sharepoint-timer-jobs-running-as-windows-azure-web-jobs.aspx

Comment: +1. I used Window Azure Web Jobs and it worked for me in the past.

Answer (score -1):

In this post you can find a detailed explanation on how to simulate a timer job behaviour with a site workflow in Office 365

[How to Create a Timer Job with SharePoint Designer 2013](https://mariagraziamerlo.com/2016/07/10/how-to-create-a-timer-job-with-sharepoint-designer-2013/)